# Download multiple text files and keep them separate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

I am trying to download multiple txt files but instead of merging them into one, I want to keep them separate and rename them - any suggestions how to best do that in Python?

Here is the idea:

```
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers

text_list=[161, 121, 105] #should be Jane Austen novels
with open(path + "directory", w):
    for text in text_list:
        text = strip_headers(load_etext(text)).strip()
        save and rename them individually in the same directory
```

Here is the code that works for the merged text file:

```
with open(path + '/merged.txt', 'w') as f:
for text in text_list:
    text = strip_headers(load_etext(text)).strip()
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: The files are on your directory (in your laptop) or on internet ?

Comment: origin files are meant to be downloaded from the internet, they do not exist on my machine

Comment: so `text_list=[text_1, text_2, text_3]` means `urls = [url1, url2, url3]`, is it correct ?

Comment: nope, those are text IDs in Gutenberg library.  The gutenberg package download command would be text = load_etext(text), right under the for text in text_list:.

Comment: Please share that code by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59013068/edit) and explain clearly your desired result.

Comment: provide the url for text_1 as example. Or how to know the url based on text_1 ?

Comment: In your code, when you do `text = strip_headers(load_etext(text)).strip()`, what is the output of `text`??

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for all the comments - enhanced the code in the question, I hope that adds clarity.

Comment: @codrelphi output of text is the actual text

Comment: If you don't mind editing once more, I recommend using actual strings for `text_1`, `text_2`, etc so the code is reproducible. Otherwise, we have to pretty much guess that it works for you and can't run it to verify. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen - done, including a working code for a merged text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would swap the loop and the file manager, iterate over each text you want to save and write it to file using a unique name (I'm assuming the `text_list` list only contains unique text names). `path` should end in a `/` and if you want to be portable, use `os.path` instead.

```
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers

text_list = [161, 121, 105]
path = "."

for text in text_list:
    with open(f"{path}/{text}", "w") as f:
        f.write(strip_headers(load_etext(text)).strip())
```

Comment: Throws an error "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: Ah, I figured `text_1` was a string. Thanks for providing your actual code. See update.

Comment: Throws an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/161'

Comment: @corio So is this working for you? Run it here: https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedBigApi

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. BTW, if you're downloading many items (dozens/hundreds), you might want to use multithreading to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the following:

```
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers

text_list   = [fn1:"text_1", fn2:"text_2", fn3:"text_3"]
saved_files = {}
for text in text_list:
    saved_file[text] = open(path + text,'w')
    saved_file[text].write(strip_headers(load_etext(text_list[text])).strip())
    saved_file[text].close()
```

Edit: deleted unnecessary import

Comment: saved_file[text] = open(text,'w') throws: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor. Also, the text_list throws invalid syntax due to the column.